# hyperref: Trouble when Using English in Chapters/Sections (Greek document)

Tags: hyperref, babel

I'm writing my thesis in latex (greek document) and I have trouble with hyperref when I put English words in chapters and sections. This problem goes away if I use only greek characters .here is a minimal example with my actual preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsinh}{arcsinh}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\gr

\chapter{τι κάνεις {\en {Hello}}

καλημέρα\cite{alice}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{alice}  \en
Carol L.,Alice in,Wiley
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Welcome, i would use `\chapter{τι κάνεις \foreignlanguage{english}{Hello}`.

Answer (score 2):

`\selectlanguage` (used by `\en` and `\gr`) does not work in bookmarks. It can be disabled after loading `hyperref`:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\selectlanguage\@gobble}
```

Also, since assignments do not work in bookmark strings, the needed code page needs to be loaded for `ucs`/`utf8x`. Either `\PreloadUnicodePage` or `\PrerenderUnicode` can be used:

```
\PreloadUnicodePage{3}
```

Third, the curly braces do not match in the first `\chapter` line. Either an additional closing brace is needed at the end of the line, but `\en` does not have an argument and group braces around `Hello` are not needed. Therefore, the simpler fix is to remove the opening curly brace before `Hello`.

Summary:

```
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\selectlanguage\@gobble}
\PreloadUnicodePage{3}
...
\chapter{τι κάνεις {\en Hello}}
```

Comment: thnx for the comments,i've tried them but I still get the message  File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg.

Comment: and it did work !!!!!thanks a lot for the help!!